# Permutate Maven dependency versions

Tags: maven, dependencies

In Maven you can define [Version Ranges](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges) for the dependency you are using. When developing a project that has several dependencies with ranges, I would like to run a build that cycles through all permutations of dependency versions to compile and test my project.

As example I have the following excerpt of a pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>[2.0,3.0)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0,1.7)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Having a look at the targeted version of those two dependencies, these are already 56 combinations.

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+
|  # | commons-lang | commons-beanutils |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2.0          | 1.0               |
|  2 | 2.1          | 1.2               |
|  3 | 2.2          | 1.3               |
|  4 | 2.3          | 1.4               |
|  5 | 2.4          | 1.4.1             |
|  6 | 2.5          | 1.5               |
|  7 | 2.6          | 1.6               |
|  8 |              | 1.6.1             |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
```

I know that this will lead to a very long runtime, as there will be a point of combinatorial explosion when having several dependencies.

This is of interest to me, as when I start with a project I tend to give certain versions of dependencies. Now when that project turns out to become a library for internal or public use, I want to support a broader range of dependencies so that I do not restrict projects that want to use the library in their library version of choice.

Up to now I have not found a way to solve this with Maven. Probably my google-fu is lacking the right words.

My current attempts lead to a pom.template which I pre-process to fill the version ranges with specific versions. Then use that generated pom within a branch of the project and get it built with Jenkins or alike.

Comment: That just seem useless for me. Fix **one** version for each dependency you use, avoid as much as possible dependency ranges, this will never help projects depending on you. Projects using your project as dependency can always override the version of your dependencies by using <dependencyManagement> version.

Comment: Maven allows dependency ranges, but Maven culture tends towards repeatability over flexibility, and concrete version numbers does that. Having said that, if it were easier to test a range of versions, then version ranges would be a nice way to indicate what dependencies your project is compatible with.

Comment: As nice as this sounds it is even less feasible as you thought. If you really want to check the full range you have to check transitive dependencies too. And you have to check several repos every time you run it whether you have all the version in the range. Not all repos might list all the versions and there can always be a new version in your ranges.